# matlab deploytool to java package javac error

Tags: java, matlab, deployment, javac

I'm trying to wrap a program of mine to work with java.
I tried a simple "hello world" first,

-hello world.m-

> disp('hello world');

I used deploytool and selected java package.

*when it reached this line:*
Executing command: "javac -verbose -classpath "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\toolbox\javabuilder\jar\javabuilder.jar" -d "C:\Users\shachar\Documents\MATLAB\deployTutorial\deployTutorial2\src\classes" "C:\Users\shachar\Documents\MATLAB\deployTutorial\deployTutorial2\src\deployTutorial2\helloworld.java" "C:\Users\shachar\Documents\MATLAB\deployTutorial\deployTutorial2\src\deployTutorial2\DeployTutorial2MCRFactory.java" "C:\Users\shachar\Documents\MATLAB\deployTutorial\deployTutorial2\src\deployTutorial2\helloworldRemote.java" "C:\Users\shachar\Documents\MATLAB\deployTutorial\deployTutorial2\src\deployTutorial2\package-info.java""

*I got this error:*
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: An error occurred while shelling out to javac (error code = 1).
Unable to build executable.

btw: when I tried standalone application / c/c++ shared library it has been compiled successfully.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the Java SDK is not installed or properly configured on your machine. Open a system terminal and execute the following two commands:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

If they both work you should proceed with the examples from the MATLAB help. If not install the Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

First you should install JAVA.
Then you must set the environment variable in "my computer"
Add a new variable named "JAVA_HOME" and set its value to your jdk path
like D:\Program\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
Then restart your matlab
and type

```
getenv JAVA_HOME
```

you should get
ans=

```
D:\Program\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
```