# how to Create a Java Package from MATLAB Code

Tags: java, matlab

In Library compiler --> Java package --> [+] `(filename.m)` after click on package it starts creating package and after some time it shows this error :

> Error: An error occurred while shelling out to javac (error code = 1).

i am using

1. Matlab: R2015a TRIAL and R2014b full but not paid
2. Java: JDK7 64bit and 8 64bit respectively,
3. OS: Window 8 64bit

i already set all paths like `JAVA_HOME`, `MATLAB_JAVA`, `path`

Please help me out

Comment: [This](https://in.mathworks.com/help/javabuilder/ug/create-a-java-class-from-matlab-code.html) might be useful for you...

Comment: to create Java package i am already following this link but it still giving error . :(

Comment: Then it might be the problem with the way you setup `Environment Variables` . Please check if they are properly set. may be a typo error issue.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455161/matlab-deploytool-to-java-package-javac-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842620/matlab-and-java-integration)

Comment: Yeah , i knew it is duplicate but what should i do when i am not getting any solution.

Comment: Please run `java -verbose` and paste the output here.

Comment: @empiric Its official website and i dont think they will change the link. moreover this link contains a lot of info and everything is essential part.So i dont think its so cool to just copy paste whtever is written in there.